# Definition of Simply Connected Domain

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

I recently got points off a test by saying that a simply connected domain was one in which a line segment connecting any two points in D is entirely contained in D. I realize why this isn't correct (because it doesn't allow for convexity), but my teacher says the correct answer is that for any simple closed curve in D, it's inside is also in D. This definition doesn't sit well with me. Wouldn't a domain consisting of two non-overlapping circles qualify as simply connected under this definition? Or is that simply connected, and I just don't understand the term?

Comment: Isn't the definition you originally gave just the definition of a convex set? A simply connected set is usually required to be path-connected and to have the property that each loop in the set can be shrunk to a point. There is no need for a simply connected set to be convex (the interior of a thick "U" is simply connected). Note too that path-connectedness eliminates the problematic pair of disjoint disks you mention.

Comment: Yeah I know that now, I wasn't thinking straight on the test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your teacher forgot to mention that a simply connected domain has to also be path connected, meaning any two points can be joined by a path (though not necessarily a straight path).

Comment: Thank you, I knew I was missing something